# Veracode scan Android : One or more recommended response headers are absent. These response headers are necessary to enable specific defense mechanism

Tags: java, android, security, veracode

Below are the details
Protection Mechanism Failure 
Description
One or more recommended response headers are absent or set to insecure values. These response headers are
necessary to enable specific defense mechanisms in compliant web browsers.

Comment: Your question is too broad and abstract. Still this is just a try to help you with response header issue. Check this link, see if it can help you in any ways: https://www.veracode.com/blog/2014/03/guidelines-for-setting-security-headers

Comment: Hi Thanks, We resolved the issue by changing findviewbyid references with Data binding and that solved my error. It was complaining about way of inflation and not about API call response headers